# How to construct a javascript regex to extract all string after a special string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string  :

```
"AED 149: "Instant Redemption A 10AED""
```

How can I have a regex that will get me this text ?

```
"Instant Redemption A 10AED"
```

currently I have this

```
var regEx = new RegExp(currency + ' ' + '[\\d,.]+: (.*)', "ig");
```

in which currency value is `AED` now.

but this return for me  `"AED 149: "Instant Redemption A 10AED""` as a match

Can I modify my regex to have this result only : `"Instant Redemption A 10AED"` ?

Comment: Use captured group #1 for `"Instant Redemption A 10AED"`

Comment: how my regEx variable will be then ? "Instant Redemption A 10AED" is not a fixed text it could be any string, but this one is fixed AED 149: in which AED = currency

Comment: Please post full relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

Transferring my comment into answer for better understanding.

Your regex is fine but `global` flag is not needed. You just need to use captured group #1 like this:

```
var currency = 'AED'    
var regEx = new RegExp(currency + ' ' + '[\\d,.]+: (.*)', "i");    
var s = 'AED 149: "Instant Redemption A 10AED"'

var m = s.match(regEx);

console.log(m[1]);
//=> "Instant Redemption A 10AED"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have always the same format you can get it without regex, just using split :

```
var my_string = 'AED 149: "Instant Redemption A 10AED"';
my_string.split(':')[1]; //Will return "Instant Redemption A 10AED"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "AED 149: "Instant Redemption A 10AED"";
str.replace(/[^\:]+\:[^\"]+\"([^\"]+)\"/, "$1");
```